# MTM Relationship GAE - NameError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am experiencing a problem when I try to add a KeyProperty on two of my classes in models.py

```
class Task(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    project = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Project, repeated=True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    task_state = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)


class Project(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    project_state = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    tasks = ndb.StructuredProperty(kind=Task, repeated=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
project = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Project, repeated=True)
NameError: name 'Project' is not defined
```

From one of the previous answers here, I have tried switching the order, but then I just got the other class as the error cause in the error log. It was initially

```
ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Task, repeated=True)
```

but after googling I tried Structured property.

The goal is to have tasks connected to a particular project, and that when I query for a certain project, I can list the tasks that are associated with it, but then when I click on the task, I can see that it is listed for a particular task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the kind of the entity, as a string, for the model you define first (Task in your code):

```
class Task(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    project = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Project', repeated=True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    task_state = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```